# selector exclusive css in particular situation

Tags: jquery

I am using :

```
$(".header.nav.nav-user").click(function(){});
```

But when i change the css to "`.header .nav .disable .nav-user`", i do not want to trigger the click event.

But in this situation, `$(".header.nav.nav-user")` also getting triggered when the css is changed to `".header .nav .disable .nav-user"`.

How can i exclude this situation?

I have tried like :

```
$(".header.nav.nav-user :not(.disable)")
```

and

```
$(".header.nav.nav-user").not(".disable"),
```

But both times it failed to get the desired result.

Please tell me ways to do this.

Appreciate for your help! Thanks.

**update**: the situation is
sometimes is:(i want to trigger click event)

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="nav">
      <dt class="nav-user">
       </dt>
   </div>
</div>
```

and sometimes is:(i don't want to trigger click event)

```
 <div class="header">
  <div class="nav">
   <dl class="disable">
      <dt class="nav-user">
       </dt>
    </dl>
   </div>
</div>
```

and the change is use other javascript,not to change that code.

Comment: $('.disable').on("click", function() { return false }); should do the trick.

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/6zjP9/, can be a propagation issue? Is the element descendant of a div and the click event will bubble up?

Comment: it may because ur might appying .disable class instead of disable otherwise your code if fine check. your class

Comment: But in the above JsFiddle, if I remove the `.not('.disable')` then also the click event does not work whereas it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dude, you are correct here at :

```
$(".header.nav.nav-user :not(.disable)")
```

except that there should not be any space in between nav-user and  :not,

```
$(".header.nav.nav-user:not(.disable)")
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zjP9/3/)

Comment: thanks,but maybe i describe no really clearly,i will update my question

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".header.nav.nav-user").not(":disable")
```

Comment: so you can pass flag variable every time to check when selector change it not trigger .trigger part use in if condition when flag true function trigger otherwise no

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the disabled attribute when you add a class of disable

For example:

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
    alert('clicked');
    $('.btn').addClass('disable');
    $('.disable').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

This will disable the link with the 'disable' class

Comment: @SAM's solution is correct. Remove the space and it should work just fine. :) Although I don't think it would work if the disable class it added dynamically.